# Compare and contrast Node.js and Servlets 3.1 nonblocking IO

Tags: node.js, jakarta-ee, servlets, scalability, nonblocking

Node.js uses the nonblocking nature of Javascript. On the other hand, Servlets 3.1 introduced nonblocking IO in Java EE 7.

Please explain technical similarities and differences between these two as far as nonblocking and scalability are concerned.

Answer (score 2):

Servlet 3.1 is multithreaded and async stream processing model hence parallel processing of tasks takes place.
NodeJS is single async threaded model.

Performance wise both are having the almost same implications. But together they can perform  what an enterprise application looks for. But i havent really tried it though i would also like to see some samples on this. I found more information [here](http://bijoor.me/2013/06/09/java-ee-threads-vs-node-js-which-is-better-for-concurrent-data-processing-operations/)

Comment: The pointed article is NOT answering the question! See the author’s comment from which I quote: “... this post is more about comparing performance of asynchronous non-blocking I/O vs blocking I/O ...”.